# NOT_FOUND when adding tasks to Google Cloud Tasks

Tags: firebase, function, queue, task, gcloud

I'm getting an error called NOT_FOUND while adding tasks to Google Cloud Tasks from the Firebase Functions. It's only 1 task that I tried to add. Not sure why this is happening.

The queue is present and from the command line, it works fine.

Here is the detailed error log:

```
Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: Requested entity was not found.
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:189:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:365:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:328:181)
    at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:187:78
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

It would save my day.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's unclear from your question but I suspect your code is incorrectly calling the method to add the Task. Please include a minimally reproducible example of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the service account email you are using, suppose you have the task object like this:

```
  const task = {
    httpRequest: {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      url,
      body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify((payload))).toString('base64'), // required by cloud tasks api
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      oidcToken: {
        serviceAccountEmail // check if this is a valid serviceAccountEmail
      }
    },
    scheduleTime: {
      seconds: sendAtSeconds // THE STUFF
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're right it was the service account which was incorrect by a letter.
Thank you so much.